# return a subset of dataframe based on a condition resulting from groupby python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame like below:

```
date|point|agent
2023-10-02|A|agent1 
2023-10-02|A|agent2 
2023-10-05|B|agent3 
2023-10-05|B|agent2 
2023-10-02|C|agent1 
2023-10-02|C|agent2 
2023-10-02|C|agent3
```

On each day at a specific point, there should be only two agents. There are cases that there are more than two, I want to return those I want to return the rows that have more than 2 agents.

I used groupby to first count:

```
df.groupby(['point','date'])['agent'].nunique()>2
```

I can use

```
df['agent_count'] = df.groupby(['point','date'])['agent'].transform('nunique')
```

and then get the the rows that have more than 2. But is there another way, without having redundant data?
I used `loc` and `iloc`, `where` and exh gives me lots of error. I am looking for an efficient way to return the rows without adding the counts to the dataframe. I did explored questions here for two hours but none of them were working.

Comment: just `df.loc[df.groupby(['point','date'])['agent'].transform('nunique') > 2]`?

Comment: You can also use `filter` as in the example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html). It's generally slower than transform, however.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks it worked! Would you like to put it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Here's how you can do it in one line.

```
df[df.groupby(['point','date'])['agent'].transform('nunique')>2]


         date point   agent
4  2023-10-02     C  agent1
5  2023-10-02     C  agent2
6  2023-10-02     C  agent3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'date': ['2023-10-02', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-02'],
    'point': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'agent': ['agent1', 'agent2', 'agent3', 'agent2', 'agent1', 'agent2', 'agent3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by point and date, and filter rows with more than two unique agents
result = df.groupby(['point', 'date']).filter(lambda x: x['agent'].nunique() > 2)

print(result)
```

```
         date point   agent
4  2023-10-02     C  agent1
5  2023-10-02     C  agent2
6  2023-10-02     C  agent3
```